# separate model logic without duplicate code

Tags: javascript, code-structure

#### Problem:

I want an action of `model A` trigger a action `noticeNewDeal` (like push notification, send mail to some user...). Usually, I duplicate those code in every relate API like

```
api 1:
const newA = modelA.create()
dealer.noticeNewDeal(newA)

api 2:
//do something
const newA = modelA.create()
dealer.noticeNewDeal(newA)
```

So I will create a function doing 2 task (create a new model and send mail). But if where i should put them, still keep the isolation of each component?

#### Example:

When creating new `deal` (record in database) i need ALWAYS notice a group `dealers`. I want to prevent duplicate code in every relate controller.
I thinking about inject `dealer.noticeNewDeal` to `deal.create` by `deal.dao.middleware.js`.

### Is that a good solution?

#### Prototype code and folder (structure by components)

[image: create new deal]

[image: update deal]

Comment: It's really not clear what these functions are intended to do.  Also, screenshots are not a replacement for a [mcve].  All in all, even if your question wasn't completely off topic for asking about opinions, it still wouldn't be answerable as written.

Comment: @Claies i use image to explain both code and folder struct, updated my question.

Comment: I don't see duplication: in the `post` you are invoking `.noticeNewDeal(...)`, in the `put` you are invoking `.noticeByNewDeal(...)`